# Replacing sub query with join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have a mysql query like...

```
SELECT OrderTransaction.buyer, OrderTransaction.parent_id
FROM  order_transactions as OrderTransaction
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT buyer
    FROM  order_transactions as dy
    left join orders as ebay on ebay.id=dy.parent_id
    where ebay.status='0' and dy.parent_id IN (
        SELECT parent_id
        FROM  order_shipping_details as ds
        left join orders as ebays on ebays.id=ds.parent_id
        where ebays.status='0'  and ebays.combined=0
        GROUP BY ds.Street
        HAVING count(ds.id) > 1
    ) and ebay.combined=0
    group by dy.buyer
) dup ON dup.buyer=OrderTransaction.buyer 
left join orders as ebay on ebay.id=OrderTransaction.parent_id
where ebay.market_type!='shopclue' and ebay.status='0' and ebay.combined=0
```

I need to optimize this query and want to remove the inner select with joins.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: write the tables description and tell us what you want to do ?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below might be running faster than the one u currently using:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1;

SELECT buyer

FROM  order_transactions AS dy

LEFT JOIN orders AS ebay ON ebay.id=dy.parent_id

WHERE ebay.status='0' 
AND dy.parent_id 
IN (
SELECT parent_id
FROM  order_shipping_details AS ds
left join orders AS ebays ON ebays.id=ds.parent_id
where ebays.status='0'  and ebays.combined=0
GROUP BY ds.Street
HAVING count(ds.id) > 1) 
AND ebay.combined= '0'
;

SELECT 

OrderTransaction.buyer, 
OrderTransaction.parent_id

FROM  order_transactions AS OrderTransaction
INNER JOIN temp1 AS tmp ON tmp.buyer = OrderTransaction.buyer
LEFT JOIN orders AS ebay ON ebay.id = OrderTransaction.parent_id

WHERE ebay.market_type! = 'shopclub' AND ebay.status = '0' and ebay.combined = '0'


Please let me know if you have any questions!
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I made some another changes in my queries and solved my problem.

Comment: I am very glad it helped! :D

Comment: Could you please mark it as the accepted answer? I would appreciated since I just started to use this site to help other people. It will motivate me to solve more problems. :D